# Command Start-Sleep -milliseconds 50

Tags: powershell, directory, sleep

Playing off of someone elses script (i know nothing) is there a way to apply this sleep to a command such as "dir"?
Goal: Display DIR output in typewriter effect.

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

$string -split '' |
  ForEach-Object{
    Write-Host $_ -nonew
    Start-Sleep -milliseconds 50
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want all the output not just the filepath or names. I offer two versions of the same concept

Multiple foreach loops

```
Get-ChildItem * | Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object {
    [environment]::NewLine
    $_.trimend().tochararray()| ForEach-Object{
        Write-Host $_ -NoNewline
        Start-Sleep -milliseconds 25
    }
}
```

Using switch statement

```
Switch (Get-ChildItem * | Out-String -Stream)
{
    default {"`n"; $_.trimend().tochararray()|
        ForEach-Object{
            Write-Host $_ -NoNewline
            Start-Sleep -milliseconds 25
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone.
I wish i could understand this stuff better :(
I understood BATCH Scripts much easer, but even there, i was very basic.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Item * | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_; Start-Sleep -milliseconds 50 }
```

Implementation with dir (Get-Item in Powershell)

Take each line from the output ($_) wait for 50 milliseconds and print the line.

Answer (score 1):

Modified your script.
This will print out each letter separately.

```
[string[]]$strings = (Get-ChildItem).FullName

$strings | foreach {
  $_ -split '' |
  ForEach-Object{
    Write-Host $_ -nonew
    Start-Sleep -milliseconds 1
   }
   Write-Host ""
}
```

Does this answer your question?